# Write a method that takes a string from the user and sends back only the even characters

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, methods, parameters, java.util.scanner

I'm a complete noob and have been working at this part of my homework for hours now im pretty sure I'm doing it completely wrong.

Ask the user for an encrypted sentence and then decrypt the sentence and output 
it. Here is the encryption algorithm: only even numbers characters are part of the 
message. For example if the user enters “Hiejlzl3ow” after you decrypt it will be the 
word “Hello”. Must write a method for this part. This method should receive a 
String as its parameter and return the decrypted String as its parameter.

heres my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class secret{
public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.print("Can you encrypt a sentance for me? \n");
       String input = console.nextLine();
       String foundMessage = findMessage(input);
        System.out.print(foundMessage);
         }
         public static String findMessage(String encodedMessage){
           for (int i=0; i<encodedMessage.length(); i++){
               if(i%2==0){
             String decode =encodedMessage.charAt(i);      
           }    
            }
          return decode; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define String decode in if statement so it can not be seen outside of that, in return statement. In addition you should add the characters in your previous decode string. Also, define method findMethod outside the main method and your problem solved.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Secret{

    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Can you encrypt a sentance for me? \n");
        String input = console.nextLine();
        String foundMessage = findMessage(input);
        System.out.print(foundMessage);
    }

    public static String findMessage(String encodedMessage){
        String decode = "";

        for (int i=0; i<encodedMessage.length(); i++){

            if(i%2==0){
               decode += encodedMessage.charAt(i);      
           }    
         }
       return decode; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want by incrementing your loop by 2...
Also, at the moment you're declaring your "decode" inside the loop; it will be recreated in every iteration, so that won't do what you want. This method should work:

```
 public static String findMessage(String encodedMessage){

   String decode;
   for (int i=0; i<encodedMessage.length(); i+=2){

      decode += encodedMessage.charAt(i);    

   }
   return decode; 
  }
```